# How to get real string from python c-api to python script?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, python-c-api

I try send a string from c++ to python string using:

```
PyObject* pyString = PyUnicode_FromString("/abc/def.html/a%22.php?abc=&def=%22;%00s%01");
....
PyObject* pyArgs = Py_BuildValue("(z)", pyString);
...
PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pyArgs);
```

But in script the string is bad:

```
function(data):
    print(data)
```

The result is:

```
/abc/def.html/a              bogus %pp?abc=&def=                    %;(null)%
```

What happened?, If I try to escape `%` chars with `%%` works fine, but `PyUnicode_FromString` is not a printf format.

Is this a bug of `PyUnicode_FromString` function?, Do I need a native python escape? Or do I need to manually escape?

Answer (score 0):

```
PyObject* pyArgs = Py_BuildValue("(z)", pyString);
```

This line is wrong. `'z'` in a `Py_BuildValue` tells it that the argument you're passing is a `const char*` and Python is to convert this into a Python string. However, the argument you're passing is already a Python string. Therefore it tries to reinterpret a `PyObject*` as a `const char*` and so generates rubbish.

The correct solution is

```
PyObject* pyArgs = Py_BuildValue("(O)", pyString);
```

which simply interprets `pyString` as a Python object (which it is!), or

```
PyObject* pyArgs = Py_BuildValue("(z)", "/abc/def.html/a%22.php?abc=&def=%22;%00s%01");
```

to skip creating `pyString` yourself.